# Connection reset by peer on systemctl as root

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, systemd, dbus

I've setup WSL 2 (Ubuntu) and I installed systemd (and systemd-sysv) there. After that, I ran:

```
sudo mkdir -p /run/dbus
sudo dbus-daemon --system
sudo daemonize /usr/bin/unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc /lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target
```

Before installing `systemd`, I updated ubuntu to the 18.10 (using `sudo do-release-upgrade` multiple times)

It worked a while but now, it only works as a normal user.
As root, I got

```
Failed to list units: Connection reset by peer
```

on any `systemctl` command.

Because of this, I can e.g. vier the status of services but I can't enable/disable the startup of dis service or start/stop them.

I could also replicate it on a clean install:

I installed Debian (WSL2) from the Microsoft Store

I executed the following commands:
    sudo apt-get update -y
    sudo apt-get install -y dbus-x11
    sudo apt-get install daemonize

Then, I executed `wsl --shutdown` on the host and run:

```
sudo mkdir -p /run/dbus
sudo dbus-daemon --system
sudo daemonize /usr/bin/unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc /lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target
```

After that, I had the same results:

```
systemctl
```

> UNIT                                                                                                                                       LOAD   ACTIVE SUB       DESCRIPTION
>
> proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount                                                                                                          loaded active running   Arbitrary Executable File
>
> sys-devices-LNXSYSTM:00-LNXSYBUS:00-ACPI0004:00-VMBUS:00-fc785225\x2d9131\x2d5661\x2dac0c\x2d3a157c61ae15-net-eth0.device                  loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/
>
> sys-devices-LNXSYSTM:00-LNXSYBUS:00-ACPI0004:00-VMBUS:00-fd1d2cbd\x2dce7c\x2d535c\x2d966b\x2deb5f811c95f0-host0-target0:0:0-0:0:0:0-block-sda.device loaded active plugged   Virtual_Disk
>   sys-devices-LNXSYSTM:00-LNXSYBUS:00-ACPI0004:00-VMBUS:00-fd1d2cbd\x2dce7c\x2d535c\x2d966b\x2deb5f811c95f0-host0-target0:0:0-0:0:0:1-block-sdb.device loaded active plugged   Virtual_Disk

and so on but when I ran

```
sudo systemctl
```

I got

> Failed to list units: Connection reset by peer

Other example:

```
$ systemctl status dbus
● dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-12-13 17:56:36 CET; 13min ago
     Docs: man:dbus-daemon(1)
 Main PID: 110
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 1.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/dbus.service
           └─110 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only

Dec 13 17:56:36 Daniellaptop systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
$ sudo systemctl status dbus
Failed to get properties: Connection reset by peer
```

[**Specifications**]

Output of `ver` on my host: `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19013.1122]`

After that I also installed `neofetch` on the Debian System(in order to show you):

```
       _,met$$$$$gg.          dan@Daniellaptop
    ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.       ----------------
  ,g$$P"     """Y$$.".        OS: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) on Windows 10 x86_64
 ,$$P'              `$$$.     Kernel: 4.19.79-microsoft-standard
',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:   Uptime: 9 mins
`d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$    Packages: 226 (dpkg)
 $$P      d$'     ,    $$P    Shell: bash 5.0.3
 $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'    Terminal: /dev/pts/0
 $$;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      CPU: Intel i7-7500U (4) @ 2.903GHz
 Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'         Memory: 80MiB / 6868MiB
 `$$b      "-.__
  `Y$$
   `Y$$.
     `$$b.
       `Y$$b.
          `"Y$b._
              `"""
```

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux <hostname of the host> 4.19.79-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Mon Oct 14 00:50:46 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

[**Note**]

It is the same result if I start the system and run

```
sudo daemonize /usr/bin/unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc /lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target
```

without

```
sudo mkdir -p /run/dbus
sudo dbus-daemon --system
```

Comment: Do a clean install and try that command. Do you see same error?

Comment: I will do it when I can(currently, I am behind a http proxy)

Comment: @Biswapriyo I've updated my question.

Comment: Debian doesn't work. I've tried it. Don't know why but Ubuntu works.

Comment: I've also tried it.(see my edit) Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible by installing `systemd` in another way as described [here](https://github.com/DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script). At first, you need to install `git`, clone this repository and run the installer as described in the `README.md`.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y git
git clone https://github.com/DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script.git
cd ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script/
bash ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script.sh
```

After that, you run `wsl --shutdown` in cmd and start WSL again.